# java split string into string array produce first value wrong

Tags: java, string, split

Input string:
-;Lokacija;-;Pozicija;Grad;-;-;

Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>();

//Load
String Row = new String("-;Lokacija;-;Pozicija;Grad;-;-;");
String[] RowAsList;
RowAsList = Row.split(";");
sortList.add( RowAsList[0] );

// Check
StringBuffer minus = new StringBuffer( "-");
String itm = sortList.get(0);
if( !itm.contentEquals( minus ) )
   // not minus
else
.....
```

Problem: this code says there is no minus on first item (0), subsequent minuses are recognized correctly.

Anyone has any ideas as to why ?

Thanks,
Kajko

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I tried debugging and it goes to '// not minus' part even when itm is "-" (and on position 0 should be)

Comment: I know you were not asking for it, but probably using `split(";", -1)` is a better fit if you need the last empty String too. (Stylistic comment: in Java the camelCase variable names are preferred. Semantic comment: please do not use static variable there, it can be very confusing, probably causing this behaviour you see.)

Comment: Debuger says: minus:count 1:(-)    and itm:count 2:(-)

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println(RowAsList);` to the code (before the `sortList.add()`) and cut&paste the result into your question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats what you want

```
public class Test
{
    public static ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String a[])
    {


//Load
        String Row = new String("-;Lokacija;-;Pozicija;Grad;-;-;");
        String[] RowAsList;
        RowAsList = Row.split(";");
        for(int i=0;i<RowAsList.length-1;i++) {
            sortList.add(RowAsList[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(sortList);

// Check
        StringBuffer minus = new StringBuffer("-");
        String itm = sortList.get(0);
        if( itm.contentEquals( minus ) )
            System.out.println(sortList.get(0));
        // not minus
        else
            System.out.println("not found...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
       String Row = new String("-;Lokacija;-;Pozicija;Grad;-;-;");

       ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>();

       String[]  RowAsList= Row .split(";");

       sortList.add( RowAsList[0]);

       StringBuffer minus = new StringBuffer( "-");

       String itm = sortList.get(0);
       if( itm.equals( minus.toString())){
           System.out.println("Get Here" + itm);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Not Here"+ itm);
       }
```

Comment: Hi, probably i did not post clear question, i do know how to get them all into list, my problem is that comparing ONLY first item returned by split is not working correctly ( hence hardcoded 0).

Comment: @user2563861 - ok then tell me what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: i want to check is FIRST (pos 0) item is "-". I know it is, code execution says IT IS NOT.

Comment: @user2563861 - try equals instead of `contentEquals`. try my above code.

Comment: Excuse me hello.. you have added ! before condition so problem occurs otherwise the code running great.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` modifier before the `sortList` member:

```
public List<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: i need it to be static